# TypeError: Cannot call method "trim" of undefined

Tags: php, rest, curl

I have some PHP that is making a cURL call to an API on a website that automates the creation of new user accounts. When I submit my form the PHP takes over but I get an error message saying:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "trim" of undefined (createUser#17)

Nowhere in my code do I try and use a method called "trim" so I'm not sure where the issue is coming from.

Here is the code I'm using with a couple of details redacted (replaced with xxxxx):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once("java/Java.inc");

// Assign form input values to variables.
$emailAddress=$_POST['emailAddress'];
$firstName=$_POST['firstName'];
$surname=$_POST['surname'];
$phoneNumber=$_POST['phoneNumber']; 

// Initiate cURL.
$curl = curl_init();

$headers = array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json','appKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$postfields = array('fname'=>$firstName,'lname'=>$surname,'mobileNumber'=>$phoneNumber,'email'=>$emailAddress);
$fields_string = http_build_query($postfields);

// Setting up cURL.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);   // Forces it to use HTTP/1.1
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

// Execute cURL.
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Display cURL response.
echo('Response: '.$response);

// Display error if POST fails.
if(curl_exec($curl) === false){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
} else {
    echo('Executed with no errors.');
};

if (!curl_errno($curl)) {
    switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
      case 200:  # OK
        break;
      default:
        echo ' Unexpected HTTP code: ', $http_code, "\n";
    }
  }

curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Comment: Is there a `createUser` file, class or method? It seems to be happening there, but I can't spot a `createUser` reference in your posted code. Maybe it's in the included `Java.inc`?

Comment: require_once("java/Java.inc");

Comment: @Loek 
createUser is the name of the method used to create a new user for the system. The end of the URL I'm using (to call the API) is ".../Services/createUser".
I have successfully called the API using Postman and there were no issues though that route.

Comment: @PredaBogdan I've tried removing the "require_once("java/Java.inc");" line and it makes no difference to the response I get from my PHP.

Comment: Now I understand, this means that the response is coming from the endoint, are you sure you are building the correct `curl` request? Maybe you are not posting the fields as a `json` body. I don't know how your post should look like but i suspect `http_build_query` should be replaced with `json_encode`. Maybe provide more info on what the request should look like.

Comment: @PredaBogdan YES!! That's fixed it! Oh my goodness, you have no idea how happy I am right now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to help, good luck!